# "readily" as an answer for someone who ask something is acceptable in spoken English?

Tags: spoken-english

This question is not about definition, but about usage.

According to Babylon dictionary the definition of **readily** is: "readily. *adv*. **with pleasure**, willingly, eagerly"
see here: http://dictionary.babylon.com/english/

My question is whether "readily" is used by native speakers as an answer for someone who makes a request in spoken English.

For example:

> Q: "Can I use your phone please for a moment?"
>
> A: "Yes, **readily**"

I know the definition of *readily*, I am asking whether this is appropriate usage.

Comment: Did you check a dictionary definition?

Comment: I'm not sure where the example is from, but the grammar is not used correctly.

Comment: Your question is a bit off. Do you mean *Can you please give me a glass of water?* which, by the way, is probably not as usual or practical as *Could you please get me a glass of water?* The *could* softens the request. And most people aren't going to be holding a glass of water that they can *give* you; most of the time a person will have to *get* (*obtain*) a glass of water from some source.

Comment: @user3169, in fact, this question was asked because what I saw in the dictionary. In my language I can use the same meaning for such answer, but the English language is not parallel to my language. I'm telling you it after a lot of mistakes that I did in the past when I tried to speak English by using my 'sense' of my language. English has its own way. Something that can be seem very simple to you as a native English speaker can be sometimes very difficult for me or other non-native English speakers.

Comment: @Wyatt, since I saw it's complicated example as you explained, hence I changed the example and I think now it's clearer.

Comment: What @user3169 is asking, or what will ask is: what dictionary definitions did you find, from which dictionary or dictionaries (please provide the link(s)) , and what about the definition(s) gave you trouble? But I think others have talked with you about this issue before.

Comment: I used Babylon-English-English dictionary: "readily. adv. with pleasure, willingly, eagerly". see here: http://dictionary.babylon.com/english/

Comment: Assiduous, you should put the link into your question, and also the definition you found there. Then state in your question what you have stated in these comments. The better question you ask  the less these types of comments there will be, and we will more ***readily*** answer your questions...

Comment: My concern is not what me as a native speaker understands. Your question hinges on two points in my opinion. 1. Is "readily" grammatically OK to use in the example? You need the definition first, so it should be added to the question. Also some words have multiple definitions, adding it confirms the OP's understanding. 2. Is the phrase what someone would normally say? "acceptable" is closer to possible (it is), or do you mean what people might normally say?

Comment: I understand you. I mean to know both, if it's possible and if it's common, even though I can guess it's less common, since I hear people saying "of course" as an answer to such questions. I never hear someone say "readily" as an answer, but I don't live in English speakers country... my assumption is just according my general knowledge from TV or from those times that I was in places of English speakers etc.

Comment: This question should be reopened. It is not about "spelling, meaning or pronunciation." It is about *usage* or *pragmatics* and even *notional functional* issues. I.e., do native speakers use such-and-such word as an answer to a request? Few if any dictionaries will address this issue. @ColleenV et al.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While grammatically correct, "readily" is not usually used as a response to a question like that.
It would be better replaced with something like "gladly".

It is more commonly used when talking about someone or something else.
For example

> Guest phones are readily available
>
> He readily loaned Bob his cell phone.

Answer (score 1):

Readily: Without hesitation or reluctance; willingly.

-Without delay or difficulty; easily.

I believe these definitions should answer your question; maybe google the definition of the word and examine the different contexts it can be used in before asking on here.

To me, this site is for questions that cannot be answered with a simple google search, but that is the correct use of "readily". It sounds a bit wonky, and is not something that would normally be said, but is still used in the right context.

Comment: @Wyatt isn't directly answering their question as well as hinting at the fact that they can simply google their answer, because maybe they didn't know it was possible, a better idea? Maybe the one who asked this question simply does not know how to effectively google search something like this, because it involves grammar, and not spelling?

Comment: @White First, welcome to ELL. Second, please see http://meta.ell.stackexchange.com/questions/439/please-everyone-details-please

Comment: Aa far as I can see, that meta post is concerning what the question poser should follow, not a cite rule or even concerning someone answering that question.

Comment: Then +1 for this answer, now that the question has been edited. *Readily* is acceptable, but not all that common, and indeed it sounds a bit wonky (although I'm not sure Assiduous knows what that means.

Comment: @White we are trying to encourage better questions, especially from repeat users such as Assiduous. Because, frankly, when such repeat users ask questions that show very little effort, I won't *readily* answer such questions.

Comment: @Wyatt thank you for your opinion, I understand your point now. I have not been on this site for a long time, and am still learning. I readily accept feedback, and appreciate your comments.